# Change - pressing back in browser no longer return to correct place in SO question list?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this is part of a recent change on SO or a change in browser behavior, but over the past couple of months, when I view the SO top questions list, follow a link to a question, then press `back` to get back to the list, I am no longer returned to the correct place in the questions list. This used to work properly and without issue. Now when I press `back` I may end up a page above (or below) where I was when I followed the link such that the question I followed is no longer visible.

I use Firefox as a broswer, and I know there have been changes to how they handle the site-set `respect no-cache header` setting (changed in FF-32), but I don't think that is the issue. I have been much busier lately and haven't been able to spend as much time on SO, so I can't determine if this is a browser or SO change. In that time I updated from FF31 to FF35, but I know SO also makes continual improvements. Has SO made changes that would effect pagination on returning to the top questions list? If so, is there anything I can do to insure that I get returned to the same position in the list after following a link? (I try to avoid opening links in a new tab) Has anyone else noticed similar behavior?

Thanks for any information you may have.

Comment: I have the same experience, but for me it started recently i.e. more or less at the same time as the new navigation was introduced on SO. I use Chrome, if that matters.

Comment: Currently having the same problem since I enabled the new navigation - clicking back in my browser returns me to the start of the questions list, not to the page number I was looking at.