# Question lists loses place in new navigation

Tags: bug, new-nav

Reproduction steps:

1. Opt in to "testing the new navigation".
2. Go to any question list.
3. Go to a page number not the first page.
4. Click on a question, then go back.
   **OR** Reload the page.

**Your place in the list will be lost and you will go back to the first page of results.**

This is problematic for any user who is

- browsing multiple posts and not habitually using open-in-new-tab, or
- doing tag cleanup work and wants to reload the list page to hide questions that no longer have the tag, or
- reading many posts exhaustively and restarts their browser before continuing.

The underlying problem (in my view) is that the page number is neither inserted into the URL when changing pages, nor (if present in the URL as in the old style navigation) used when loading the list afresh.

Related:

- I believe [Change - pressing back in browser no longer return to correct place in SO question list?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287576/change-pressing-back-in-browser-no-longer-return-to-correct-place-in-so-questi) is a report of the same problem (but I am posting this as a new question so as to make a clear bug report as I am much more confident in my observations).
- [This person just wants to be able to specify page in URL.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321140/unable-to-change-page-number-manually-entering-page-parameter-in-url)

Comment: Reloading on a page other than the first sending you back to the first is [currently by design](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312499/the-new-nav-pagination-links-are-broken-on-the-homepage#comment284762_312524) unfortunately. I am hoping that your post makes them change their minds.

Comment: @Kendra That sounds more like “we haven't gotten to improving this aspect yet” than “it's a feature”. But yes, I posted this in part as “this is actually bad, really, here's some use cases”.

Comment: @KevinReid I was browsing through the [new-nav](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-nav) section tag  today and noticed your question. I only noticed it after I posted [a question of my own](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338871/1415724) which seems related.