# Clicking on related questions tag/TAB does not show/redirect to newest posts - beta nav system

Tags: feature-request, bug, new-nav

I was introduced to the new (beta) nav system yesterday and I must say that I like it a lot.

However, there is something that I seem to be unable to find/do in order to get back to the newest (php) posts on [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) which is the main tag I follow.

- Note: This is the case for any tag and isn't *php-specific*.

When I am in the php thread and I click on the "2" pagination (or any other number), I don't know how to get back to the main [php tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) page to see the newest php posts.

I literally have to click on the ["php" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) on one of the questions in the thread (or a question) in order to get back to the newest posts, or [page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?page=1) at the bottom's pagination *(see the edit below regarding test(s) performed)*.

I spent quite a lot of time in order to find an option to do this, but alas to no avail.

Is there something I've missed or I don't know about?

*Sidenote:* I added the "feature request" tag, since I am unsure if it is a bug *(should it be tagged as a bug?)* or it should be a feature request. 
Please retag accordingly if I did not tag it properly.

**Screenshot 1:**
[image]

**Screenshot 2:**
[image]

**Screenshot 3:**
[image]

**Screenshot 4:**
[image]

**Edit:** As stated in comments: *"You can also refresh. Refreshing will take you back to page one."*

That does work, however I shouldn't have to refresh the page. I believe there should be a way to click on the tag so that it does go back to the newest posts or clicking on the "Newest" tab as I used to do in the old system.

On an added note; if I clicked on page 2 or any other pagination number, I should be able to see the posts on those pages when refreshing it as done in the old system. In refreshing the page, I then lose the questions (thread) that were shown in there, where I have to click on page 2 (or 3, 4, etc.) to get back to them again.

The new (beta) system's URL doesn't change as it does in the old system.

I.e.:

Old system's url in the address bar (remains the same by doing browser refresh):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?page=2

New system's url in the address bar remains as:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Which is why by my refreshing my browser, would bring me back to the main (newest) page.

The almighty questions (for now) are:

- Am I forced to go back to using the previous system?
- Will this be taken into consideration and modified in order to be able to click on the "php" tag *(or any "other" tag for that matter)* that does appear as a hyperlink to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?

As shown in the second screenshot **("Screenshot 2:")** where it reads as *"Clicking here does not make it go to the newest posts"*.

Theoretically, by clicking on that "hyperlink", it should redirect to the newest questions.

**Test(s) performed:**

- **(Test #1:)** If I click on that tagged hyperlink by opening it in a new browser tab, it does take me to the main tagged page with the newest questions shown.
- **(Test #2:)** If I click on the "home" or "voted" tab then click on (php) tag/tab after, it does show the newest questions and the pagination number at the bottom of the page is highlighted as **"1"**.

IMHO, that action should happen simply by doing a standard mouse click on the said tag, rather than a "right-click open in new tab/new window" or mouse-wheel click or clicking on another tab then back to the hyperlinked tag.

Comment: You can also refresh. Refreshing will take you back to page one. (Supposedly [not a bug.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312499/the-new-nav-pagination-links-are-broken-on-the-homepage#comment284762_312524))

Comment: @Kendra It does indeed work and thanks for that. However, I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Yup, which is why it's a comment and not an answer. :)

Comment: I wonder if they're still working on it. The release candidate was announced over a year ago, it's still wearing the beta label and most of the more recent feedback doesn't get a [status-*] tag.

Comment: @Stijn I also wonder the same. I've made another edit to my question near the bottom. You'd think that by simply clicking on what appears to be a hyperlink, would take it back to its page's origin, rather than still displaying content that are on page 2, 3, 4 etc. and remaining on the same page.